# is there any way to check and change some file encoding type in the same time in golang?

Tags: go

i use `golang.org/x/text/encoding/charmap` package and below code for changing file encoding and it works well.

```
data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(*file)
checkError(err)

encode := charmap.Windows1256.NewDecoder()
transform, err := encode.Bytes(data)
checkError(err)

err = ioutil.WriteFile(string(*output), transform, 644)
checkError(err)
```

now i want to work with some other encoding type too but the problem is there is no way for working with or checking other encoding for changing the file encode or walking `charmap` package for check encoding unless using switch/case for checking every encoding type and there are a lot encoding type and i feel this is wrong way to do this, so is there any solution for make this coding process more productive?

thank you for help.

Comment: "there is no way for working with or checking other encoding for changing the file encode or walking charmap package for check encoding unless using switch/case for checking every encoding type" Yes, that is correct. "and there are a lot encoding type" This is correct too. "and i feel this is wrong way to do this" This is wrong, sorry. This is the only way to achieve what you want. "so is there any solution for make this coding process more productive?" No, sorry. You cannot determine encoding. All you can do is try. Encoding is 100% **meta**data.

Comment: You can try in the order of most-likely encoding first and use the first one. What you try to do is basically undoable.

Comment: thank you for response.

Comment: actually i want to user choose the encoding type and this undoable makes me worry but again thanks.